# the search for algolia display all the data before doing the search

Tags: php, laravel, autocomplete, algolia, instantsearch.js

I installed the algolia package, I configured it, it works fine, but there is still a problem, it is that the data displays in input search before doing the search.
see the site for more information.
site: [link](https://www.aswaktinghir.com/annonces)

**searche.blade.php**

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="search-box">
        <!-- SearchBox widget will appear here -->
    </div>
    <div id="hits">
        <!-- Hits widget will appear here -->
    </div>
    <div class="aa-input-container" id="aa-input-container">
        <input type="search" id="aa-search-input" class="aa-input-search" placeholder="Search for posts" name="search" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>
</div>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/instantsearch.js@2.0.2/dist/instantsearch.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/instantsearch.js@2.0.2/dist/instantsearch.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/template" id="hits-temp">
        @{{ __highlightResult.h1 }}
        <div class="row song">
            <a class="song-link" href="song/@{{objectID}}">@{{{_highlightResult.title.value}}}</a>
        </div>
    
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            const search = instantsearch({
                appId: 'H329YTS1B5',
                apiKey: '10a91d843aaeef2d91583bfead9b339f',
                indexName: 'title',
                urlSync: false
            });
            // initialize SearchBox
            search.addWidget(
                instantsearch.widgets.searchBox({
                    container: '#search-box',
                    placeholder: 'Search for posts',
                    wrapInput: false,
                    cssClasses: {
                        input: 'form-control'
                    }
                })
            );
            // initialize hits widget
            search.addWidget(
                instantsearch.widgets.hits({
                    container: '#hits',
                    templates: {
                        empty: 'No results',
                        item: $('#hits-temp').html()
                    }
                })
            );
            search.start();
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the search query is empty, the search matches *all records* by default.

You'll need some additional code if you want to suppress results when the search box is empty:

https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/conditional-display/js/#handling-empty-queries